# Unable to make table layout to appear elevated with margins

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Im trying to create a table layout with elevation. Following is my code,

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:background="@drawable/box">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Compliance Details: "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statutoryText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Statutory: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statutoryValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="statutory value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statNatureText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Statutory Nature: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statNatureValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="statutory nature value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complianceTaskText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Compliance Task: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complianceTaskValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Compliance task Value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/compDescText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Compliance Description: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/compDescValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="statutory value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/penalConsText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Penal Consequences: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/penalConsValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="statutory value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comFreqText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Compliance Frequency: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comFreqValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="statutory value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/compOccText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Compliance Occurence: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/compOccValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="statutory value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appLocText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Applicable Locations: "
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appLocValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Applicable Locations value"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In order to create margin around my table layout, im using the following code which is `box.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

The problem is that, the table layout outer margins are still not visible. I have added box.xml as a background for my tablelayout yet the same problem is persisting. How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add`android:layout_margin="10dp"` in your `TableLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ViewCompat.SetElevation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setElevation(android.view.View,%20float)) method on your table layout

It's found in the support library.